# Unable to execute jq command in golang

Tags: go, terminal, jq

I'm trying to pass a json data to `jq` command and replace a value like `sed`. But it's just printing the command and not executing it.

```
jsonStr, _ := json.Marshal(p.Values)
op, _ := exec.Command("echo", string(jsonStr), "| jq '.aws=1'").CombinedOutput()
fmt.Println(string(op))
```

It's just printing the `value of p.Values` which is a json and `| jq '.aws=1'` instead of replacing the `aws` key in `p.Values` and printing it.

The output is something like this.

`{"name": "n1"} | jq '.aws=1'`

But if I execute the same command from terminal, it's working fine and replacing the text in json.

Comment: `echo` will print it's arguments.

Comment: You are not executing a shell, so it is not going to interpret the arguments as a shell would.

Comment: a command-line shell like `bash` will interpret the `|` as a pipe and know to run one command, relaying its `stdout` to the next command's `stdin`. In your code snippet you are running a single command `echo` with 2 arguments - that are simply printed.

Comment: You cannot use pipelining `|` in exec.Command, pipelining is a shell feature and the go `exec` package does not invoke a shell. You need to run a second `exec.Command` and set it's `Stdin` to the value of the first's `Stdout`.